# Retry for failed file upload using HTML input=file form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have an upload script that works fine, using PHP move_uploaded_file from a POSTed input[type=file] HTML form.

Every now and then, the upload fails, usually from a server timeout.

I have been unsuccessful in a search for how to retry the upload without the user having to input the file again.

Any suggestions for best practice as to how to do a server side (or Javascript or JQuery) retry without user intervention?

For those who asked to see code, here it is, although it's irrelevant to my question:

1. AJAX request

   ```
    var request = $.ajax({
    url:   upScript, 
    type:  "POST",
    data:  data // includes $_FILES object
    });
   ```

There are callbacks as well.

2. HTML

   ```
    <div class='photospot emptyPhotospot' id='ph1'>
    <input type='file' class='photoFile' id='uf1'>
    </div>
   ```

(input is triggered by JQuery event handling)

3. Server-side

   ```
    function uploadFile($path) {   // $_FILES object must exist
      $allowedMaxSize = 6000000;   // 6 MB size limit
      $allowedExt = array('jpg','pdf','gif','png','txt'); //  file types approved for upload

      if (!$path || !is_dir(dirname($path))) return 1;
      if (!$_FILES) return 2;
      $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // temp location on client drive

      //file extension validation
      if (count($allowedExt) > 0) {
        $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (!in_array($fileExt, $allowedExt)) return 3;
      }
      //file size validation
      if (filesize($tempFile) > $allowedMaxSize) return 4;

      //upload file
      if (!move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $path)) return 5;

      // all ok
      return 0;
     }
   ```

Again, not looking to debug code here, it works 95% of the time, only fails due to server timeout.

For those who shut down the 1st version of my question, THIS IS A THEORETICAL DISCUSSION only on how to retry a failed upload for those who have been down this road..

Comment: Because your server is failing, it'd be best to re-try the request from the front end and use Javascript to retry the request. You'll need to catch an error response from the server and trigger the same upload script again. Be careful to set a flag or some other quit condition so that you stop re-trying at a certain point.